# Accessing navigation file in parent folder only displays without css styles

Tags: php, file

I am trying to access my navigation.php file so I can include it in my login.php file. Like so:

```
<?php

include "../navigation.php";

?>
```

but the navigation only displays without css styles. For some reason this ONLY happens with I add a folder within the root folder of the project I am working on with php files. How do I access the navigation php file from a child folder?

Here is a screenshot of my file folder: 
[image]

Comment: Try outputting your current directory with var_dump(getcwd()) The output will tell you the relative path of your script, then you can navigate to parent folders and be sure you have the right path

Comment: `code: include('../navigation.php');`

Comment: @elizabethD. the css styles still will not show up

Comment: the styles are inside the navigation or style.css?

Comment: the styles are in style.css

Comment: but then why do you ask for the navigation?you need to include the styles in you login ...anyway you do that like this `code include('../../styles.css');` here is the answer explained [path link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory)

Comment: @elizabethD. The styles for all of my pages are in style.css. And the navigation is in the navigation. I am unsure of how that is confusing. Still not working.

Comment: @elizabethD. Thanks for the help. It turns out I just had to add a link in html on the login.php page.