# Cannot include php file from parent directory

Tags: php, directory, include

Before you mark this as a duplicate from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory), I can't get it to work. This is my situation:

**Directory**
parent-folder/sibling1/main.php
parent-folder/sibling2/wanted.php

So in my main.php file I want to include the wanted.php. Because of plugin functionality I cannot move the file to the same folder, I have tried this, but then the php file is not working any more.

***My attempt**

```
<div class="parent">
<?php include('../sibling2/wanted.php'); ?>
</div>
```

I have tried many suggestions from other threads, but above is not working, how do I get this right?

Comment: Would you mind if you try `_DIR__ . '../sibling2/wanted.php';` something like this

Comment: `include __DIR__ . "/../sibling2/wanted.php";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include files from parent or other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks for marking duplicate, while I already pointed this out in my first sentence :(

Comment: @Demian because u pointed out that doesn't mean it's not a dup

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the directory structure in place and therefore, what the working directory of the PHP running when "main.php" is executed. Best way to find that out would be to call the function getcwd() and to output on the page, its output.

```
<h1>Current directory : <?=getcwd();?></h1>
```

Then knowing what this directory value is, you should be able to then get the correct path to use as an include for your "wanted.php" file.