# How to set the ROOT for all PHP imports in a directory?

Tags: php, html, import

I have some web pages where I use php to import page elements. On each page, I set the root. Within the HTML, I import other code that I use such as libraries, the navigation bar, and the footer. Here is the code:

Sets the root to import from:

```
<?php define(ROOT, '/var/www/html/my-project');?>
```

Imports all the css and javascript for the page:

```
<?php require_once ROOT.'/imports/a-libs.php'; ?>
```

Imports the navigation bar:

```
<?php  require_once ROOT.'/imports/b-menu.php'; ?>
```

Imports the footer:

```
<?php  require_once ROOT.'/imports/c-footer.php'; ?>
```

Is there a way that I can define the root for the other imports in one file rather than having to have the root definition in each file?

Also, according to `<?php phpinfo();?>`, the root of the project is '/var/www/html/', but I needed to get into the 'my-project' directory, so I added that to the ROOT definition. Is there a way that I can call and append getcwd to my project? Something like this:

```
 <?php define(ROOT, getcwd().'/my-project');?>
```

I tried it, but the page goes blank when I do that and no errors are showing in the web console.

Comment: If you have access to php.ini, try changing "display_errors" to "On" and include the errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

[getcwd()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) provides you the current working directory. `echo getcwd();` and see what is the current path and adjust file paths in `require_once` accordingly.

If you have directory structure like this:

```
/var/www/html/my-project/library.php
/var/www/html/my-project/imports/a-libs.php
/var/www/html/my-project/imports/b-menu.php
/var/www/html/my-project/imports/c-footer.php
```

then in `library.php` you can use

```
<?php

define( 'ROOT', getcwd() );
require_once ROOT . '\imports\b-menu.php'; 
require_once ROOT . '\imports\c-footer.php';
require_once ROOT . '\imports\a-libs.php';

?>
```

OR

```
<?php 

define( 'IMPORT', getcwd() . '\imports' );
require_once IMPORT . '\b-menu.php'; 
require_once IMPORT . '\c-footer.php';
require_once IMPORT . '\a-libs.php';

?>
```

Now you can [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) `library.php` in any other php file with proper path to access `ROOT` or `IMPORT` constants.

```
<?php include 'library.php'; ?>
```

Also read following:

[Include files from parent or other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory)