# file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty with json file

Tags: php, json

I have a function that is supposed to return the json file as an array to be further manipulated else where, however I have run into an error.

> file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Here is my code:

```
function __getBlacklistAsArray__() {

    return file_get_contents( json_decode('config/list.json', true) );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT 1:

If I call the same function from a file in my root directory it works fine and if I print `json_decode(file_get_contents('config/list.json'), true)` it works and will display the contents of the json file.

However if I call the function from another page outside of my root directory, it gives and error.

> file_get_contents(config/list.json): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

---

EDIT 2:

uVal.php

```
$accepted_domains = __getJSONArrayFromKey__('accepted_email_domains');
```

index.php

```
function __getJSONArrayFromKey__($str) {

    $arr = __getBlacklistAsArray__();

    if(isset($arr[$str])) {

        return $arr[$str];

    } else {

        return $str . " is not a valid key.";
    }
}
```

```
function __getBlacklistAsArray__() {

    return json_decode( file_get_contents('config/list.json'), true );
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the functions in a diff order json_decode(file_get_contents('filePath'), true);

Comment: Can you share a full working example that triggers the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include files from parent or other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory)

Comment: (The duplicate is about using `include` from different folder level depths, but you can apply the same here for `file_get_contents` of course.)

Comment: PATH is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/why-would-i-use-dirname-file-in-an-include-or-include-once-statement

Comment: In EDIT 1 you do `json_decode(file_get_contents('config/list.json'), true)` but in your function you have `file_get_contents( json_decode('config/list.json', true) );` which seems the wrong order to call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('config/list.json'), true);
```

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(config/list.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Point to the correct filename... check if `file_exists(filename)` before read it!

Answer (score 0):

It should work like :

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('path/filename'), true);
```

if you get warning of failed to open stream: No such file or directory then please check your file path or use `__FILE__`