# Php script not finding include file

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line

I am running a php command (edited) from the command line that runs a php file on the web server.

In that file I need to include a file that is one level up from its location.

I have tried

```
include(../the_file_in the parent.php)
```

and every other suggestion I could find here for the last two days.

I keep getting the same error in the CLI:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/html/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No su
ch file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-admin/email_processor.php on line 16
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/html/wp-load.ph
p' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/wp-admin/email_processor.php on line 16
```

As with all thing computing, I have a sneaking suspicion this is ridiculously simple...that’s why it is taking so long to get it sorted.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful:

```
<?php
  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/parentfilepath/filename.php";
?>
```

or

```
include __DIR__ . '/../parentfile.php';
```

Comment: Thank you!  __DIR__ did the trick. I found that shortly after posting the question in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory/48367611#48367611