# Get root path of server in php

Tags: php

So it seems similar questions have been asked but i Couldn't find an answer that works for me. What i need is the path of the server's root, its a linux based server. So the files i am working on are in 
`/var/www/html` so when i do things like `getcwd()` or `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` i get `/var/www/html` but what i actually need is outside of /var its in /usr. which means when i login to the server and am at / . /var and /usr are different paths. How can i get the / of the server so even inside `/var/www/html` i could get say files from `/usr/share`
[image: So this it the root right]
As you can see it has two dirs of my interest. First there is var in which i can go like `/var/www/html` and have all my php files. the other is usr in which i have some folders that i need to access from my php files. Now all i need is to be able to access the usr folder from the php files inside my `/var/www/html` dir.
And by files i dont mean by include i mean by readdir() because there are font files there that i need to send as an api response.

Comment: I know right, people down vote without giving a reason. this is the cons of using Stackoveflow. Anyway, back to your question - you ever tried `echo dirname(__FILE__);`?

Comment: What does it mean "get files from /usr"? php files with `include`? what problem do you have if you use the full path? When you log in you are probably chroot'ed.

Comment: @HadiPawar have you tried `define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));` to be modified for your issue? Or you could define the server path with `define('BASE_URL', 'web-server-path')..` to be used when necessary.

Comment: let me add some screenshots to help

Comment: i have added more details hope it helps in understanding the problem.

Comment: @Gabriel thank you for your response unfortunately i only get /var/www with that . as you can understand i have to go way back and be able to get /usr folder that is outside of the current working directory or its root.

Comment: So `opendir('/usr/share');` fails? What's your [`open_basedir` setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)?Show us what have you tried and what errors you are getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example:
You can use absolute path for include which you can define and use

```
define("DOCUMENT_ROOT", '/usr/share/');
include DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'file.php';
```

[Include files from parent or other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826567/include-files-from-parent-or-other-directory)

Comment: Yeah i just figured providing /usr directly allows it to open. no need to append the server name or anything at the beginning. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$root = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") ;
 Echo $root;

Comment: Format this into a code block and fix the incorrect uppercase syntax of `Echo` to `echo $root;`.